# How to make sure if a process is correctly terminated in Java

Tags: java, sqlplus, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to run sqlplus which will execute some sql scripts. The code I use is:

```
String[] command = { "sqlplus", myDatabaseConnectionInfo, "@C:\script1.sql",  "C:\output.log"};
probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = probuilder.start();
```

In the sqlplus syntax above, I would like to log the output to a log file: output.log, therefore I do not need to get the "process.getInputStream()" here. But I want to make sure that this process is really terminated before the rest of my code are continued executing. Because sometime I realize that the rest of my code are executed before my sqlplus process is finished. Can anyone help me how can I make sure if a process is terminated in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Try [exitValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) maybe.

Comment: `process.waitFor()` should work

Comment: @soufrk this will throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` "if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue--

Comment: @daniu thank you, so that means waitFor() will wait until the process is completely terminated before continuing executing the rest of the code?

Comment: Never used it myself - I've read that it sometimes doesn't work properly, but it should (if the documentation is to be believed). Best try it out yourself.

Comment: ok thank you very much